# How can I change the spacing between labels and inputs?

Tags: html, css

I want all of the inputs to align with each other, but it seems that because the renminbi and won currency symbols are larger, they are pushing their inputs further away. I tried adding negative padding (which did nothing) and negative margins (which also moved the inputs), but neither worked. How can I reduce the spacing between these two inputs and labels?

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 210vh;
    background-color: orange;
}

.inputs {
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    max-width: 768px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.input {
    margin: 15px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 15px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
```

```html
    <main>
        <section class="inputs">
            <label for="usd" class="">$
                <input type="number" name="usd" id="usd" class="input" placeholder="Dollar">
            </label>
            <label for="euro" class="">€
                <input type="number" name="euro" id="euro" class="input" placeholder="Euro">
            </label>
            <label for="yen" class="">¥
                <input type="number" name="yen" id="yen" class="input" placeholder="Yen">
            </label>
            <label for="renminbi" class="">元
                <input type="number" name="renminbi" id="renminbi" class="input" placeholder="Renminbi">
            </label>
            <label for="won" class="">₩
                <input type="number" name="won" id="won" class="input" placeholder="Won">
            </label>
        </section>
    </main>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add a wrapper around the emoji characters so that you can declare `label` as a parent, making the emoji characters and `input`s as grid children. The reason this is necessary is because raw text nodes cannot be targeted via CSS.

From there, we can define our columns and control the spacing how we'd like. For the columns, the emoji to take up one fraction unit (`fr`) and have the remaining space in each row occupied by the input (`auto`).

```
label {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 0 0.25rem;
}
```

Chrome has a nice grid inspector which visualizes the above explanation nicely.

[image]

**Demo**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 210vh;
  background-color: orange;
}

.inputs {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 768px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.input {
  margin: 15px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

label {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto;
  gap: 0 0.25rem;
}

label i {
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section class="inputs">
    <label for="usd" class="">
      <i>$</i>
      <input type="number" name="usd" id="usd" class="input" placeholder="Dollar">
     </label>
    <label for="euro" class="">
      <i>€</i>
      <input type="number" name="euro" id="euro" class="input" placeholder="Euro">
     </label>
    <label for="yen" class="">
      <i>¥</i>
      <input type="number" name="yen" id="yen" class="input" placeholder="Yen">
    </label>
    <label for="renminbi" class="">
      <i>元</i>
      <input type="number" name="renminbi" id="renminbi" class="input" placeholder="Renminbi">
    </label>
    <label for="won" class="">
      <i>₩</i>
      <input type="number" name="won" id="won" class="input" placeholder="Won">
     </label>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Would it be possible to use <span> instead of <i> so you do not need to set the font to normal? Also, did you mean to add "align-items: center;" twice for <label>?

Comment: @Vadventra Absolutely. The element you use (as long as it's not a block level element) can be anything. A `<span>` makes sense to me—any element without any semantic meaning.

Comment: And do I need to put "align-items: center;" under label twice?

Comment: @Vadventra Typo. Removed duplicate line.

Comment: Thanks again. When you set the gap to 0.25rem, what did you assume the font-size to be/how many pixels did you mean to add?

Comment: @Vadventra I was assuming the `font-size` to be `1rem`, or whatever the default font size is set to be of the document (`16px`) by default. The `gap` is not needed, though, since you added left padding to the `input` itself.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your input fields are wrapped within `<label>` tags, I assume you were adding padding/margins to `<label>` tags and that obviously wouldn't help your case. So first of all, you can create a separate div which would wrap your label and input field. for example:

```
<div class="field-wrapper">
    <label for="usd">$</label>
    <input type="number" name="usd" id="usd" class="input" placeholder="Dollar">
</div>
```

After that, you can use [CSS Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) to align label and input fields next to each other, for example:

```
.field-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

After which they should be equally aligned, otherwise you can define width for `.field-wrapper label` and that should work perfectly.